# peer to peer connection between android application and .net c# application using only wifi

Tags: c#, android, connection

Suppose there are two applications. One on android and one on windows(c#.net). What I want to do is that I have a database on my pc and I can access it using the c# application. Now what I want to do is that I want to send a data (JSON for example) to the pc application, then the c# application uses that data to populate the db, and then return a response to the android application.

The hard part (the part I don't have a clue about) is that I don't know how to create this connection between these two platforms. There shouldn't be a router or any other additional hardware involved. I want to be able to use only pc's and android device's wifi.

Does anyone have any suggestions? (any protocol, service, sample app etc)

Comment: You can run any web server inside your C# application (for example you can run wcf service: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee939340.aspx). Android application will then connect there over wifi.

Comment: it works if both devices are in the same connection (or at least this is the thing that I know). But as I said in my question, I want this connection to be peer to peer and I don't know how to set it up in the first place

Comment: Every Android device can act as a hotspot. So then let your pc connect(over wifi) with that hotspot.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but there are two concerns about your answer. First I want the pc to act as the server. and second I searched all over the internet about how to establish a hotspot on android programmatically. Do you know about its APIs in android?

Comment: Even if the Android is the hotspot the application on your pc can be the server.

Comment: Read SO of today. I saw a post about programmatically doing so.

Comment: could you give me a link please?

Comment: No because then i had to search. It was tagged `android`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124921/discussion-between-roostaamir-and-greenapps).

Comment: Why do you need peer to peer by the way? You said you publish data to PC, wait for response, it returns you result back. Well even if you don't want to wait for response - WCF supports duplex communication, so if you establish connection from android to PC - you should be fine. Now if you want to initiate connection FROM PC to android, that's another thing.

Comment: There is no internet connection (or router) in the situation that the clients want to use the application. As you siad, I want the android device(s) connect to the pc, and send the requests. How can I establish the connection at the first place? and then, could you give me a simple code example with wcf?

Comment: I wonder why buying/supplying a 30 dollar wifi router would not very easily solve your problems. You do not need internet for that.

Comment: It is a little complicated, but They want to use the application in somewhere that looks like a cave with no internet connection or wifi-router. That is all I can say

Comment: A pc can act as a hotspot too with a wifi network card.

Comment: how? what resources do I need? I don't have a clue about a library or api that does that